# Given a dictionary and a list of floats L, how to find which keys has the closest value to each value in L?

Tags: python, binary-search

Input1:

```
d = {1: 0.2, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.5, 6: 0.7, 7: 0.7, 8: 0.8, 9: 0.95, 10:1}
L = [0.48, 0.72]
```

Expected result1: [3, 6]

Input2:

```
d = {1: 0.9, 2: 0.88, 3: 0.88, 4: 0.76, 5: 0.76, 6: 0.7, 7: 0.5, 8: 0.44, 9: 0.2, 10:0}
L = [0.48, 0.77]
```

Expected result2: [7, 4]

You can assume the values in d is sorted (always increase or decrease as the key gets bigger)
If there are values that are equal, return the smallest key.

I'm able to do this in O(n), is there a better way to use binary search to do this?

Comment: A dictionary isn't really the right data structure here - they're only good for finding exact matches.  Binary search in a sorted list would be the simplest solution, and Python has a built-in `bisect` module that will do most of the work for you.  However, it's only going to find the next smallest (or next largest) value, you'd need to do some additional work to find out which adjacent value is actually closer.  But that's a constant amount of work, so it's still O(log n) total.

Comment: If you can assume that `d[k] < d[l]` if `k < l`, and maybe that each key from `1` to `len(d)` exists then yes, you could use binary search.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I was thinking to add another step like getting keys and values out as lists first, then do binary search? Not sure if the complexity added on that + binary search is better than just do it in a loop in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution - without thorough testing - but it's not better than O(n):

```py
def find_closest(source: dict, targets: list) -> list:
    result = {}
    for idx, target in enumerate(targets):
        last = None
        for key, val in source.items():
            if not last or abs(target - val) < last:
                last = abs(target - val)
                result[idx] = key
            elif abs(target - val) > last:
                break
    result = list(result.values())
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d1 = {1: 0.2, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.5, 6: 0.7, 7: 0.7, 8: 0.8, 9: 0.95, 10: 1}
    L1 = [0.48, 0.72]

    d2 = {1: 0.9, 2: 0.88, 3: 0.88, 4: 0.76, 5: 0.76, 6: 0.7, 7: 0.5, 8: 0.44, 9: 0.2, 10: 0}
    L2 = [0.48, 0.77]

    d3 = {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.3, 4: 0.4, 5: 0.5, 6: 0.6, 7: 0.7, 8: 0.8, 9: 0.9, 10: 1.0}
    L3 = [0.48, 0.77]

    d4 = {1: 0.9, 2: 0.8, 3: 0.7, 4: 0.6, 5: 0.5, 6: 0.4, 7: 0.3, 8: 0.2, 9: 0.1, 10: 0.0}
    L4 = [0.48, 0.77]

    print(find_closest(d1, L1))
    print(find_closest(d2, L2))
    print(find_closest(d3, L3))
    print(find_closest(d4, L4))
```

```
[3, 6]
[7, 4]
[5, 8]
[5, 2]
```